# Is the Doctor Who episode 'Blink' the first use of the phrase "timey-wimey"?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

Was the phrase "timey-wimey" (or time-y wimey) used in *Doctor Who*, or elsewhere,  before it appeared in the script of the 2007 episode "Blink"?

Comment: Wasn't there an episode with Davidson's Doctor where he was trying to explain how time worked, said it was "timey... wimey... never mind"? I think it was an offhand comment, but I'm still racking my brain for which episode, and I just don't happen to have access to those particular episodes at the moment. Perhaps some other dedicated Whovian might know?

Comment: @SbaraJackson: you might be thinking of [‘Time Crash’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Crash) the Children In Need mini-episode where David Tennant’s Doctor meets Peter Davison’s Doctor. They both say “wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey” simultaneously whilst working out why Davison’s Doctor looks older than he did when he regenerated. (This episode was broadcast between the end of series 3 and the 2007 Christmas special, i.e. after ‘Blink’.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In *Doctor Who*, the first time was in *Blink*, yes. At least, in the TV series. There might have been other DW material before that (novels or audio plays), which I missed.

Can't be sure about "elsewhere". I certainly did hear it then for the first time.

Comment: Do you take into account the original series?

Comment: @Eregrith Yes. I watched lots of episodes when they first aired, and have caught up with most material which I didn't, and I feel pretty confident in saying there was no mention of timey-wimey, wibbly-wobbliness before 2007.

Comment: I tried some dictionaries today. I found the "timey" in "old-timey" and "ragtimey": so it seems to be North American. No sign of "timey". So I have accepted your answer Mr Lister, and I think we can safely say that "timey-wimey" is a DW coinage, probably by script writer Steven Moffat. <br> Thank you!

Comment: When I wrote 'no sign of *timey*' I meant 'no sign of *wimey*'.